# SVG Filter Displacement as Overlay on Entire Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

I have a project where I want to achieve a glass effect through a lens, running over the entire site. I tried with PixiJS, but it only works on the canvas. It's important that the filter is on every element on the site. I've succeded in putting an SVG displacement filter on the body through CSS, and it distorts (!) but the body and everything on the site, is also only visible through the image, I'm using to displace.
Is it possible to achieve a glass lens, running over the site using SVG filters, or is there another way which is better? 
Here is the code I have so far
I did not write the js entirely by myself. I found an example of displacement here https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/WQyBJb 
For reference this is the effect I'm after, but without canvas https://zumi.gucci.com/ 
And how would I go ahead an animate the SVG feImage? I tried with the setAttribute x and y, but it doesn't move

Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Glass Displacement</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.1.5/pixi.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <filter id="displace-filter">
                <feImage id="displaceImg" x="512" y="512" width="100%" height="100%" result="displaceImage" />
                <feDisplacementMap  id="displacement-map"
                                    xChannelSelector="R"
                                    yChannelSelector="G"
                                    in="SourceGraphic"
                                    in2="displaceImage"
                                    color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
                                    scale="100"
                                    result="displacementMap"
                                    />
                <feComposite in2="displaceImage" operator="in" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/X0Tavx1j8Wc" alt="">
        <h1>Bornholm</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="glass"></div>

    <script src="svgdisplace.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: system;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local(".SFNSText-Light"), local(".HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Light"), local(".LucidaGrandeUI"), local("Ubuntu Light"), local("Segoe UI Light"), local("Roboto-Light"), local("DroidSans"), local("Tahoma");
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "system";
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    filter: url("#displace-filter");
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 11.089em;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 75vw;
    height: 75vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50%;
}

#glass {
    background: chartreuse;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    /* filter: url(#noise); */
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 500px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.wrapper h1 {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```
var xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
var imgUrl = "_assets/displace2.png";
var feImage = document.querySelector("feImage");
var displaceImg = document.getElementById("displaceImg");
var speed = {
    x: 2,
    y: 1
};

toBase64(imgUrl, function(data){
    feImage.setAttributeNS(xlink, "xlink:href", data);
});

function toBase64(url, callback){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
}

animate();

var tx = 0;
var ty = 0;

function animate(){
    tx += 0.027;
    ty += 0.031;
    displaceImg.setAttribute("x", speed.x);
    displaceImg.setAttribute("y", speed.y);

    speed.x += 0.1;
    speed.y += 0.1;

    renderer.render(stage); */
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Here is the image, I'm using to displace 
[image: displacement circle map]